# command to search string in linux environment

Tags: grep

i have unix directory path. this directory contains 5 sub-folders.
under each subfolder, i have 10 files (similar). this sub folder means each site or location files.

I want to search a particular number present in each five subfolder.

i am currently using grep command which is useful to find string in a sub folder, but not in all sub folders

grep -l search string *.
this is performing for a sub folder.
i want to do search for all five subfolders using one single command.

Comment: You might be looking for `grep -l whatever */*` or `grep -rl whatever .` but you're being vague enough that I'm not sure I understand what you want.

Comment: suppose my search string is 404 566 7898, then how is my command look like grep -l "404 566 7898"

Comment: As zwol suggested, try `grep -rl "404 566 7898"` or `grep -l "404 566 7898" */*`

Comment: What I'm confused by is not the search string but the directory structure.  Is it exactly two levels deep? Are there files at intermediate level(s) that should also be searched?  Are there any files at any level that should *not* be searched, and if so, is there a shell glob pattern that defines the names of the files that *should* be searched? Does that vary per directory? Do you need to include hidden files and/or directories in the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using one single command` - why? UNIX is built on the philosophy of using combinations of the right commands to achieve the best results, why would you want to do something different?

In this case, the UNIX tool to **find** files is named `find` and the UNIX tool to **G**lobally search for a **R**egular **E**xpression within a file and **P**rint the result is `grep` so the right approach for your problem is a combination of `find` and `grep`, e.g.:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l regexp
```

Comment: Yes this is the command i used to find the string in multiple folders under single directory. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -r
```

is what you want

man grep
/--recursive

```
-r, --recursive
Read all files under each directory, recursively, following
symbolic links only if they are on  the  command  line.
Note that if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory.
This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
```